# WPF TextBlock not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I have a standard texblock bound to a property in my viewmodel

```
  <TextBlock  Grid.Row="3"  Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MyErrorMessage, Mode=Default,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Foreground="Red"></TextBlock>
```

The property

```
private string _errorMessage;
        public string MyErrorMessage
        {
            get { return _errorMessage; }
            set
            {
                _errorMessage = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(this.MyErrorMessage);

            }
        }
```

I do a standard

```
 this.MyErrorMessage = "Login failed";
```

But the textblock is not updating. I can see the the setter and getter being called correctly, but still the textblock is not updating. Am i missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property that is raised should have the string "MyErrorMessage" and NOT the value of the property. i.e.

```
this.RaizePropertyChanged( "MyErrorMessage" )
```

If you fix this (and everything else is also set correct), you'll be fine.

Side comments: There is no need for Mode=Default (as the name suggest, it is the default), and UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged (also the default, and doesn't make the code more readable).

Comment: Thanks, now i have to figure out why this method works in all my other modules

Comment: Must be stressed, forgot my lambda expression. This is how i normally write it. this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.MyErrorMessage);

Answer (score 0):

RaisePropertyChanged takes a string 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx

So just change the call to

```
this.RaisePropertyChanged("MyErrorMessage");
```